# Returning response from function lead to error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous

I have the current code in PasswordSrvc:

```
  doResetPassword: function (passwordCommand) {

    var response = {data : {errors: ""}};

    if (passwordCommand.password !== passwordCommand.passwordConfirm) {
      response.data.errors = response.data.errors.concat("Passwords do not match!\n");
    }
    if (passwordCommand.password.length < 6 || passwordCommand.passwordConfirm.length < 6) {
      response.data.errors = response.data.errors.concat("Password too short!\n")
    }

    if (response.data.errors !== "") {
      return response;
    }

    else {
      passwordCommand.token = $location.search().token;
      return $http.put(apiUrl + 'password/doResetPassword', passwordCommand);
    }
  }
```

which is called from:

```
PasswordSrvc.doResetPassword($scope.passwordCommand).then(function (response){
        console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
        if (response.data.errors) {
            $scope.errorMessage = response.data.errors;
        } else {
          $location.path('/authority/passwordChanged');
        }
      });
```

The problem is that I always get the response as being "undefined" if a validation error occurs and I end up returning from:

```
    if (response.data.errors !== "") {
      return response;
    }
```

Why does this happen? How can it be fixed?
I mean, when returning from

```
    else {
      passwordCommand.token = $location.search().token;
      return $http.put(apiUrl + 'password/doResetPassword', passwordCommand);
    }
```

it works fine and I get whatever I want, but why doesn't it work for the "manually created response"?

Thanks

Comment: Slightly off topic, but you should probably use `var errors = []`, then use `errors.push(...)` wherever you're using `response.data.errors.concat(...)`, then use `return {data : {errors: errors.join('\n')}};` where you're returning. It'll make your code a lot more concise.

Comment: you should return promisse from your _doResetPassword_, but if errors you return plain object

Comment: you can see about [$q](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)

Comment: can you provide a plunker with your working code? i can modify it for sample

Comment: for example something like: `if (response.data.errors !== "") {
      return $q.when(response);
    }`

Comment: Where to place this?